# Installing Ubuntu alonside Windows 8

Tags: system-installation

How do I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 without having to partition the hard drive.  Can someone please explain in detail to a newbie.

Comment: *Partitioning* the hard drive means setting space aside for Ubuntu's ext4, while *formatting* means erasing the whole hard drive.  Why don't you want to add a partition?

Comment: @Seth That is not correct. Formatting means writing a new, blank filesystem to a partition. Volumes are formatted; physical drives are not. Formatting is a narrower, higher-level action than partitioning. Writing a *new* partition table ("erasing" the drive, even though by itself this hardly destroys any information) is not formatting, though occasionally it's called "low-level formatting." Actually overwriting the entirety of physical disk to render the data it contained unrecoverable is neither formatting nor partitioning.

Comment: @EliahKagan Okay, I know.  I didn't *completely* explain *every aspect* of the task.   Was just trying to clear up a misunderstanding if there was one.

Comment: If your computer came with Windows8 pre-installed then an even better answer may be here: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Answer (score 3):

If you don´t want to create a Partition for Ubuntu you have to Install it via [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

And I recommend that you [turn off fast startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) in Windows-8, when using it along with any Linux Distribution